# What's the difference between new-itemproperty and set-itemproperty?

Tags: powershell

Both appear to create or change an item property.

What's the difference between the two? Under what circumstances do they perform differently?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me the difference is that if you use new for an item property that exists you'll receive an error, you can use set-itempropoperty in all cases.

So new is for creation, and set is for modification or creation. New will not create if the property exists.

Comment: I just tried in HKLM:\software\test. "gp ." shows no itemproperties. "set-itemproperty . MyProperty MyValue -type string" creates a property which "gp ." now shows. "new-itemproperty" does the same but expects a "-value" switch before MyValue.

Comment: Then I tried "set-itemproperty . My2 4 -type dword" and checked with regedit. I have a value named "My2" with a content of 4 of the type dword.

Comment: You are right I just don't see the -Type parameter to set-itemProperty. Just stay the fact that you can't use new-itemProperty for a property that exists.

Comment: I noticed you edited your answer. It's correct now and accepted. Ta.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what @JPBlanc mentioned, there is another important difference. Note that only New-ItemProperty has the parameter `-PropertyType`, which can be used to specify the registry value type (like REG_DWORD etc.).

Comment: The `Set-ItemProperty` cmdlet has the `-Type` parameter which can be used to change the type of a registry value.